# Dynamic DataGrid Columns and Content in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have the following XAML code:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="tabs" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visibility}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0">
                    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource     CCCItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subtypes}" />
                    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CCCFileItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" />
                </WrapPanel>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Where the tabs themselves are being added dynamically via XAML with `tabs.DataContext = fileTypes;`.
Each tab has it's own DataGrid, associated with a "FileType" class.
Each FileType class has a `public ObservableCollection<SecondaryFile> Files { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SecondaryFile>();`, and each SecondaryFile has

```
public ArrayList Columns { get; set; } = new ArrayList();
...
public string[][] data { get; set; };
```

Is there anyway to bind the columns and data to the grid via XAML?
Keep in mind the TabItems and matching DataGrids are dynamic themselves, as is the number of columns and their contents.

I tried giving the grids a name in a dynamic fashion so I can access it programmatically, but to no avail.

Any suggestions would be more than welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly `SecondaryFile` contains these two fields where `Columns` holds the `headers` of your DataGrid and `data` holds the rows.

If this is the case, and you want to populate the DataGrid with these two dynamically using only xaml code, I propose to use a DataTable. To do so you have to omit both `Columns` and `data` and use a single DataTable object insted, which you will later bind as a `ItemSource` to your `DataGrid`. In addition you need to set the `DataGrid`'s `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `True`.

To create your data table

```
public DataTable table  { get; set; }

// Here we create a DataTable 
table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));    

// Here we add DataRows.
table.Rows.Add(1, "john", "doe");
table.Rows.Add(2, "jane", "doe");
```

And in the xaml you will have something like

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files.table}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, using Path=Files.Table does not seem to work. My current workaround is creating another DataTable under FileType, and using Merge to merge all the SecondaryFile's columns and data within it.
Am I missing something when using the Path=Files.Table? Should I, perhaps, bind the fileTypes variable to something other than DataContext?

Comment: Since I do not have your complete files I can not say for sure what is the problem. Try to change your first line (in the examplar code) `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and the the name of the 'root' object you are binding. If not mistaken it should be `="{Binding fileTypes}"`.